# Duplicate Key Error MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Trying to get all of the data from the `employee_id` column in staff table and `INSERT` into `employee_id` column in `employees` table.

I receive a duplicate entry for key error. I have tried using `REPLACE INTO` and `IGNORE INTO`. The script is only affecting the first row of the `employees` table and is inserting the `employee_id` but changing all other fields to null.

```
require 'config.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO employees (employee_id) SELECT employee_id FROM staff";

if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: is the employees table empty?

Comment: No, the employees table has data in each field except for "employee_id"

Comment: then you need an update querry, not insert

Comment: You're probably looking to use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into how to use update instead insert. I did look at ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE earlier but couldn't understand how to apply it.

Comment: You need to provide more details regarding the schema and existing data of those two tables. What you SHOULD do is a combination of `UPDATE employees ... FROM staff WHERE ...`, and `INSERT into employees ... SELECT ... FROM staff WHERE staff.employee_id NOT in (SELECT employee_id FROM employees)`, but that could be improved with joins, and is better done with code.

Comment: Sorry guys. Still cant quite figure this out. I cant manage to get an update query working. Would i be better updating the "employee_id" column of employees from the CSV file used to populate the staff table?

Answer (score 0):

If the only attribute you are applying in your insert query is "employee_id" and you are getting a duplicate key error with insert/ignore and replace, then employee_id is not the primary key of the employees table, AND something else is defined as the primary key (or a unique index). If you had provided the table structure this would have been obvious.

Comment: So the insert is not working because "employee_id" is a primary key in one table but not the other? Is it possible to work around this without changing the structure of the tables?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing more information than is appropriate for a discussion here. Assume "no"